# Can any one explain this Python behaviour?

Tags: python

I have a problem with understanding this code.

I called `dd` 3 times, but why is it not deleting the previous stack of the function each time?

I am getting this output:

```
11
12
13
```

Could you explain a solution? Also, where else could this problem occur?

```
class Hello():
    v=10

class K():
    a=Hello()
    def p(self):
        self.a.v=self.a.v+1
        print(self.a.v)
        self.a=None
def dd(): 
    ff=K()
    ff.p()
    del(ff)
dd()
dd()
dd()
```

Comment: You're changing the `a` class attribute of `K` so it affects all instances of the class

Comment: `a` is a class variable and is shared between all instances of `K`. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Comment: thanks guy i understand now ..

Answer (score 0):

When you delete ff, you are deleting a new object that inherited properties from K (which inherited properties from Hello()).

When properties are inherited to an object, they change together, but do not get deleted together. You will need to reinitialize the properties to get them to change back.